# Compression library for Cross Platform

Tags: compression, cross-platform

```
  We need to compress and send the data  from each of the endpoint client (IOS/Android/Windows Classic) and decompress it in serve end using .NET.
```

Is there any open source common library for compress/decompress which can be used in this scenario (common X platform).

```
  Pl advise.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just about any programming platform developed it the past 20 years supports [zlib](http://zlib.net/) out of the box. Since they generally all incorporate the same free library, the data they generate is interoperable.

Look through API documentation for keywords like "zlib", "gzip", or "deflate". For example, in Android, check out [Deflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) and [DeflaterOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) which implement zlib.